# How to switch Trainers in Rock Band 3 Pro Mode?

Tags: rock-band-3

So I finally got my Squier Stratocaster and the Midi controller for Rock Band 3's Pro Mode and wanted to try the training mode. But I got welcomed by the message:

> You must use the instrument associated with this Trainer.

While the last training I did was with the keytar, I was now controlling with the midi controller. Logging in with a second account through the keytar didn't help either.

So how can I switch to the correct trainer or make sure Rock Band 3 recognizes the correct instrument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you change the switch on the MIDI adapter to "G"? There's a switch on the top of the adapter to toggle it between drums, keyboard, & guitar.

[image]

Comment: Nope, that turned out to be the case, I feel pretty stupid right now...

Comment: Don't worry about it. My problem is that I routinely forget to flip the switch on the back of the Squier to turn the stupid thing on. (Just not a habit, since I don't need to turn any of my other guitars on.)